# How do I move collections/meshes

Tags: edit-mode

I forgot to select my original collection before 'appending' some other blender 'projects' and also before I imported some gltf's.
Now my collections are 'messy'.
How do I fix my initial collection so that all added collections are at the same 'level' see attached. All the original meshes can be seen at the bottom and added blenders and gltf's at the top top of the list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select objects and hit <kbd>m</kbd> to move them to some other collection, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to just link objects to another collection(objects can be in multiple collections) and you can also just drag the objects from one collection to another in the Outliner in View Layer mode(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + drag to just link instead of moving) and there is also Collections panel in the Object Properties tab of the Properties Editor in case that's somehow convenient to edit what collections the object belongs to.

See more in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html#collections-menu).

Comment: Thanks Martynas. Something else I have now learned although I must be more careful in future to select the object before appending etc.